# Google Map is not displaying properly in javascript popup

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google map API to display map in simple javascript popup. While popup opens it will display as below:
[Map Preview in Javascript Popup http://122.170.97.189:81/gmap/preview.png](http://122.170.97.189:81/gmap/preview.png)
I tried auto refresh div using Jquery for map div like:
    $('#map').fadeOut('slow').load().fadeIn("fast");
It refresh the map div but still the problem is not solved.
If I press F12 in chrome and firefox the map is displaying correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the google maps code to render the map after the popup is fully loaded. You should call `google.maps.Map()` inside `$(document).ready()` or after some timeout (`setTimeout()`).

When map object is created it tries to figure out how big the canvas is and if popup is not fully loaded yet it may get wrong values.